# How to track when custom email is verified in aws ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am implementing a SAAS software where my customers will be able to send email using their custom from email. I am using AWS SES.

I created a custom email template and can send the email. User click on the link and email gets verified. But how my system will be updated when user click and verify the email?

boto3 API: send_custom_verification_email

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to ses events (click, open, etc). There are different ways to consume event — SNS, CloudWatch, etc.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity.html

As for verifying the email, it depends, if you're using a third-party service then it should handle it for you. If not, then you'd have to handle it yourself in the backend, you can redirect the user to the page and verify in the backend.